# Temporary table does not show up in the database after created

Tags: mysql

I use the following query to create temporary table but the table does not show up in the database nor give any error while executing the query.

```
 $sql2 =    "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp_result` (
  `tscore` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `validsc` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `des` varchar(100) NOT NULL
)";
mysql_query($sql2);
```

After creating tempory table i am going to insert some data into it.

```
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO temp_result (tscore, name,validsc, des) VALUES ('$L', 'L-Scale','1', '$desl'),('$F', 'F-Scale','1', '$desf'),('$K', 'K-Scale', '1', '$desk'),('$HS', 'Hypochondria','0', '$deshs'),('$D', 'Depression', '0', '$desd'),('$HY', 'Hysteria', '0', '$deshy'),('$PD', 'Psychopathic-Deviation', '0', '$despd'),('$MFM', 'Masculinity-Femininity','0', '$desmfm'),('$PA', 'Paranoia','0', '$despa'),('$PT', 'Psychoastenia','0', '$despt'),('$SC', 'Schizophrenia','0', '$dessc'),('$MA', 'Hypomania','0', '$desma'),('$SI', 'Introversion Social','0', '$dessi') ";
mysql_query($sql3);
```

But I am not sure why table is not creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "DBNAME";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE fbsign (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
sname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
mob VARCHAR(50),
pass VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
     
    $ins="insert into fbsign (fname,sname,mob,pass)values('$fname','$sname','$mob','$pass')";
    $ex=$conn->query($ins);
    if($ex)
    {
        echo "Inserted successfully::";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR::";
    }
    
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Nothing happens. neither table get created nor data got inserted

Answer (score 3):

temporary tables aren't created in the database, they are by session and stored in memory until the session is ended.

Comment: Then how I suppose to insert or retrieve data from the table. Because when I used `echo` command to display the certain data from the database the data is not there.

Comment: After the temp table is created, doing an insert on it should populate it.  Depending on the SQL platform, you may have to do more.  If your using a CTE then you'll need WITH prior to the insert.

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with this. I have no idea how to do that. I just want to create a tempory table which can last up to the end of the session.

Comment: which platform are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP and mysql for database

Comment: I am using that table to display result ones I change my page (move to the other web page) the table should drop.

Comment: What does your output show when you try to create the table.  Can you query it from memory with no data in it to get no results?  The syntax for an insert into the temp table looks fine, but what is occurring that makes you think it's not populated?

Comment: When I use this following query to display some data from the temp_result it gives me no value.

Comment: `$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM temp_result WHERE tscore = '$a' AND validsc = '0'");
 //$res2 = mysql_fetch_array($res1);
 
 while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($res1)):
 $res = $res2['name'];
 echo "<div class=tab-pane active id='profile'>
   <table class='table'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>&nbsp;You are diagnosed with symptoms of $res </tr>
    </tbody>
            </table>
  </div>";
 endwhile;`

Comment: @Ameya Is your select query using the same db connection as the one that creates and populates the temp table?

Comment: yes, the select query is using same database connection.

Comment: What results do you get if you try this query immediately after table creation - select * from information_schema.innodb_temp_table_info;

Comment: No result 

`TABLE_ID  || NAME  || N_COLS SPACE  || PER_TABLE_TABLESPACE  ||  IS_COMPRESSED`

this is a blank table

Comment: @Ameya Last question, can you confirm that the db account has the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE privilege? - select `create_tmp_table_priv` from mysql.user where user = 'your_user' and host = 'your_host';